# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I keep getting this error when attempting to execute this code, even after placing a CType around the value and defining it as double?

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    ' The deletion of the individual row is automatically handled by the GridView.
    Dim dbDelete As New pbu_housingEntities
    ' Remove individual from the bed.
    Dim occupant As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text
    Dim room As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Text
    Dim building As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Text
    Dim find_id = From p In dbDelete.Residents _
                  Where p.person_name = occupant _
                  Select p


    Dim remove_bed = From p In dbDelete.Beds _
                     Where p.occupant = find_id.FirstOrDefault.id _
                     Where p.room = room _
                     Where p.building = building _
                     Order By p.id Descending _
                     Select p
    remove_bed.First.occupant = CType(0, Double)
    dbDelete.SaveChanges()

    ' Increase number of open spaces in room.
    Dim update_occupancy = From p In dbDelete.Rooms _
                           Where p.room1 = room
                           Where p.building = building _
                           Select p

    update_occupancy.First.current_occupancy = update_occupancy.First.current_occupancy - 1
    dbDelete.SaveChanges()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that CType line is where the error is?  You don't even check if find_id has a value before you use it in the next LINQ statement.  That could be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in this line:

```
Where p.occupant = find_id.FirstOrDefault.id _
```

Are both of these of the same type?  The reason I suspect this line is because in another table earlier, you're using `occupant` as the name of the person.  I would check that the other values in your where clauses also match the types that you are comparing them to as well.

The reason that it may appear that the error is in the assignment line is that the query isn't being performed until you run `First` on it.  The error is most likely in the query, not in the assignment.

Comment: @Scott - he'd be getting a NullReference exception if FirstOrDefault returned a null value.  `find_id` is guaranteed to be non-null but it may be an empty collection.  I just think that the type of `id` is different than `occupant`.  There may be an error there waiting to happen, but I don't think it's hitting that error in this instance.  FYI, I didn't see your comment until after I had written my answer.

Comment: @Scott -- I don't know, room and building could be non-string types as well in the DB, though given the names it's hard to see how they could be.  I don't know why any of them would be doubles.  Everything seems to be countable or named so why use a real type?  And why track how many people are in a room in a column (if that's what occupant is)?  Why not use a join between people and beds to track occupancy and simply delete the entry in the join table to free up a bed?

Comment: Yea I was confused by the logic as well, but looks like we were right about the line being the issue. =D

Answer (score 0):

It can't convert empty string to a double. Put in an if statement checking for an empty string and if it is empty then set the double to 0.